# Squeezebox show custom content (no iframe)

Tags: javascript, mootools, joomla3.0, squeezebox

I'd like to show some custom (HTML) content on a squeezebox (within Joomla).
To show an iFrame I'm using this code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    SqueezeBox.open('https://whatever.com', {handler: 'iframe'});
});
```

Thats working fine. But how can I display whatever I want?!